# Expire post request to S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, postman

I'm trying to do a post request to S3 by postman, but I receiver the `response code 403 - Forbidden`. The CORS and the policy are rights, and I using a url presigned:

```
url = _client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket=_BUCKET_NAME, Key=key,
    Fields={'acl': 'public-read', 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'},
    Conditions=[
        {'acl': 'public-read'},
        {'success_action_status': "201"},
        ['starts-with', '$key', ''],
        ['content-length-range', 0, 100000],
        {'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'},
        {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg'}
       ],
    ExpiresIn=expiration)
```

The response in the postman:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Request has expired</Message>
    <Expires>1970-01-05T04:00:00Z</Expires>
    <ServerTime>2019-06-11T12:40:50Z</ServerTime>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
    <HostId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the bucket's policy. I fixed the `Resource` changing `"arn:aws:s3:::mi-stagging"` to `"arn:aws:s3:::mi-stagging/*"`